# Add an item to a list for Rules and References

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

I have a Node Reference in Users.

When I set Add an item to a list with Node identifier for some event, it doesn't add.
It looks like this

```
Add an item to a list
Parameter: List: [account:field-badges], Item to add: 28
```

Set a data value works with comma separated list.

Comment: Have you added an action to save the entity after updating the field?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The "add an action" form says: "To make entity fields appear in the data selector, you may have to use the condition 'entity has field' (or 'content is of type')."

My field was in the data selector but the item was not added by the action.

I changed the action to a rule with a condition "entity has field" as requested, the field being the one I wanted to add a value to. Then I recreated the action in the actions area.

This was the solution for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems in the pass with setting a variable with Actions.

Try this:

1. Add [new] Action -> Add a variable -> Integer -> 28 -> label: badge_number & machine_name:variable_badge_number
2. Inside your 'Add an item to a list' action, click 'Switch to data selection' and change 28 to the new variable.   I believe when done, the data selector textfield should read 'badger-number'